# Spring pick highest priority bean

Tags: java, spring

With a config like this:

```
class MySpringConfig {
  @Bean // Lowest priority
  @Qualifier("pri1")
  Bean beanPri1() { ... }

  @Bean // Medium priority
  @Qualifier("pri2")
  Bean beanPri2() { ... }

//  @Bean // Highest priority
//  @Qualifier("pri3")
//  Bean beanPri3() { ... }
}
```

and a service like this:

```
@Service
class MyService {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("pri1")
  Bean beanPri1;

  @Autowired
  Bean beanWhateverTheHighestPriIs;
}
```

Is it possible to tell Spring to inject:

- `beanPri1` (since that was given by `@Qualifier`) into `Service.beanPri1`
- Whatever the highest priority bean is into `Service.beanWhateverTheHighestPriIs`

using annotations or something similar that can be reused relatively easily across configurations and different bean sets?

Examples with the above configuration and doing the following changes:

- No changes: `Service.beanWhateverTheHighestPriIs` should be `beanPri2`
- Uncommenting `beanPri3`: `Service.beanWhateverTheHighestPriIs` should be `beanPri3`
- Commenting `beanPri2`: `Service.beanWhateverTheHighestPriIs` should be `beanPri1`

Comment: This is normally resolved using `@Profile` above the beans. As you cannot change the instance at runtime (assuming your code example) it seems like the best fit. Define a bean for different profiles and decide on startup which one to take. Another way would be to autowire `List<Bean>` an use a custom method to lookup the "best" instance which in my opinion is less preferable as you will have to do this in every location you autowire said bean. Maybe extend your question about what you want to achieve (the real use-case,not this abstract technical question) so we can give more focussed answers

Comment: If I were you I would see how Qualifier annotation is implemented and would do the same with my custom HighestOrder annotation that resolves the bean with highest priority instead of by name...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@Order annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order) to tell spring which to use first

Comment: I tried that, however that resulted in all beans still being considered as candidates and resulting into non-unique bean exceptions. My understanding is that `@Order` is only for ordering them when injecting into `Collection<Bean>` type of properties - so the higher priority ones come before. Am I right or is there a way to tell it to inject only one?

Comment: @levantpied actually, there are many caveats related to this (e.g. `@Priority`, `@PriorityOrdered`, `@Bean` vs `@Component` etc.) - but you're right, `@Order` by itself won't usually work - quote from `determineAutowireCandidate` doc from `spring-beans`: `Looks for @Primary and @Priority (in that order).` - `@Order` is not used in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use @Value annotation with expression that resolves the collection of ordered beans and then uses [0]  to return the one with the highest order.